# How to custom data classes on Yolov6? my data class don't work

Tags: yolo

**Question** How could I set my custom classes on yolov6?

I have tried this:
https://github.com/meituan/YOLOv6/blob/main/docs/Train_custom_data.md

my data.yaml:

train: ./data/volleyball_07_03/img_label/images/train
val: ./data/volleyball_07_03/img_label/images/val
test:  ./data/volleyball_07_03/img_label/images/val
is_coco: False

nc: 5           # 類別數量
names: ['player','libero','umpire','volleyball','net']

this is my inference result:
https://github.com/pei-ci/photos/blob/main/test_1.jpg?raw=true

I don't have the class named person, but it appears in the results.

my data.yaml can work on yolov5!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Aadd `--yaml data/data.yaml` into:

```
python tools/infer.py --weights output_dir/name/weights/best_ckpt.pt --source img.jpg --device 0
```